# Need exact media queries for Kindle Fire

Tags: css, kindle-fire

I'm designing for the Kindle Fire, but am not finding correct information about the CSS height/width.

On my two devices, this is what I measured:

**Fire 7" 2015**

600 x 1024

**Fire HD 8" 2018**

601 x 962

I thought that it was always either 600 or 800 (and maybe more for bigger, newer ones), but that is clearly not the case.

Are there *exact* media queries (and I mean 601 exact) for the Kindle devices?

Can I trust that 601 will always be the larger 8" screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I collected information on my website to see what size devices people were using.

```
$(window).width();
```

These are the widths that can used for CSS media queries. The model number (KFSUWI) is from the user agent. I then Googled the tablet size (HD 10) using the model number. The widths were calculated with Javascript running on the page.

**Kindle devices**

**KFSUWI, KFTBWI (HD 10)**

800 
1280

**KFAPWI (HDX 8.9)**

800
1219

**KFDOWI, KFGIWI, KFKAWI (HD 8)**

601
962

**KFFOWI**

600
1024

**KFSOWI (HD 7)**

534
802

**KFSAWI (HD 7)**

800
1280

**KFTHWI (HD 7)**

600
902

**KFHDX (HD 7)**

600
(no data)

**KFAUWI (HD 7)**

600
1024

**KFOT**

600
963

**KFARWI**

534
812

**KFTT**

534
802